# Is there a way to use GflAx to incorporate gradient colours?

Tags: image-manipulation, gradient

Ok, narrow question of the day.  I'm using [GflAx](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/pierre.g/xnview/engfl.html) (from [xnview](http://www.xnview.com)) to create some graphic tiles.  I would like to put some gradients in as well though.

Is there a way I can do this within this product?

There is also an SDK which is part of this product but I can't find that info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this but you can create the gradient in another program and then do a "LoadBitmap" make the mods you need ontop of that 'background' and then save to a new file.